# PHAR doesn't work after compiling

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine, phar

I'm trying to compile [Symplify/EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard) to PHAR.

I tried automatic PHAR compiler [MacFJA/PharBuilder](https://github.com/MacFJA/PharBuilder) which is great and works for other packages. But there is a problem with EasyCodingStandard package. Compiling is OK. But when I try to run compiled PHAR file, I get an error.

> Unused binding "$skip" in service "Symplify\EasyCodingStandard\Console\Application".

[image]

There is probably problem in doctrine Dependency Injection. Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Seems your using an old version from them warning messages: https://github.com/MacFJA/PharBuilder/issues/12 then its failing to load in the classes `Symplify\\EasyCodingStandard` as the lib is not handling errors its just saying its been built without issues, try with new version or use something like [box2](https://github.com/box-project/box2) instead which works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for box2. I tried to compile my code with it but the resolution is the same - https://pasteboard.co/Hj09FKe.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in [symfony/dependency-injection](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection). PHAR doesn't support glob ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.stream.php#104320)) which symfony/dependency-injection uses.

Workaround is quite easy. [This commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26845/commits/67f66e0034c31fa596866e50312f48a2d208743e) will fix the problem with PHAR in symfony/dependency-injection. So you can just download the code via composer, then manually update the file based on that commit and that's all. After building PHAR it will works.

Answer (score 0):

### 2020 update

ECS now has compiled `ecs.phar`

https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/pull/1734